# Oracle 19c Select Query with Database Link

Tags: oracle, query, select, oracle-19c, database-link

How can I use the following query with database link:

```
set pages 999
col "Size MB" format 999,999,999
col "Objects" format 999,999,999
col OWNER for a25
select obj.owner "Owner", 
       obj_cnt "Objects", 
       decode(seg_size, NULL, 0, seg_size) "Size MB" 
  from (select owner, count(*) obj_cnt 
          from dba_objects 
         group by owner) obj, 
       (select owner, ceil(sum(bytes)/1024/1024) seg_size 
          from dba_segments 
         group by owner) seg 
 where obj.owner=seg.owner(+) 
 order by 3 desc, 2 desc, 1;
```

I tried different ways but in all I got the error ORA-00933 "SQL command not properly ended".

Regards.

Comment: What do you mean 'use it with a database link'?  There's no reference to a db link in there. And as far as I can tell, there should be no need for one.  A database link is to allow one database to act as a client to another, and it is accessed by appending the name of the db link to the name of the table in the remote database:  SELECT * FROM REMOTE_TABLE@LINK_NAME;

Comment: @EdStevens Hi, actually here we will compare two databases. I want to see the result of remote vs current database using minus for this query. If you know how I can do this with the select I sent, can you help? Also, I already created a database link. I'm asking how can I use it with this query.

Comment: What line and column are you getting an error on?  The query you posted appears to work for me.  Are you running a different query to try to incorporate the database link?

Comment: @JustinCave The query works of course. When I use DBLINKNAME after from, it doesn't work. I'm asking how can I do this, that's all.

Comment: every Oracle database has a table DUAL, that you can select by `SELECT * FROM DUAL;`. Do you know how to select the DUAL table from the remote database that can be accessed by the database link?

Comment: @jrdba123 - Can you show us the query you're actually running?  I'm not sure what "use DBLINKNAME after from" means.  If you add `@DBLINKNAME` after both of the table names in your query, the new query would work.  My guess is that you're not doing that.

Comment: @JustinCave thank you so much. I noticed that the operation could not be completed due to a syntax error. It will be like this: select obj.owner "Owner", obj_cnt "Objects", decode(seg_size, NULL, 0, seg_size) "Size MB"
from (select owner, count(*) obj_cnt from dba_objects@PRODLINK group by owner) obj, (select owner, ceil(sum(bytes)/1024/1024) seg_size from dba_segments@PRODLINK group by owner) seg where obj.owner=seg.owner(+) order by 3
desc, 2 desc, 1;